# How to generate string using for loop in JQuery in ASP.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have to generate a string in Jquery by looping the List as follows

```
events: [
        {
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: '2014-11-01'
        },
        {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2014-11-07',
            end: '2014-11-10'
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2014-11-09T16:00:00'
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2014-11-16T16:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Conference',
            start: '2014-11-11',
            end: '2014-11-13'
        },
        {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2014-11-12T10:30:00',
            end: '2014-11-12T12:30:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Lunch',
            start: '2014-11-12T12:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2014-11-12T14:30:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Happy Hour',
            start: '2014-11-12T17:30:00'
        }
    ]
```

The list contain these elements but I'm unable to generate this kind of string .I've tried in two ways

```
for(var i=0; i<customers.length; i++)
            {
            "{"

                "title:" +customers[i].Column1+","
                "start:"+customers[i].Column3
                "}"


            if(i!=customers.length-1)
            {
                ","
            }   

            }
```

and

```
           $.each(eventList, function (index, employee) { 
        {
      title:employee.name,
      start:employee.date
       }
     ,
      });
```

but I'm unable to get proper result please give me solution for this .To get list I'm using the following coe

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         contentType: 'application/json',
         url: 'ProjectedYieldCalender.aspx/GetData',
         data: '{}',
         success:
            function (data) {

                var eventList = data.d
               eventList=demo(eventList);
                initCalendar(eventList);
            }

     });

 });
 function initCalendar(eventList) {
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    //defaultDate: '2014-08-12',
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: [
      eventList
    ]
});


 }
```

Thank you

Comment: Seems you suffer from wishful thinking. Please look at MDN how to assign content to variables

Comment: Is the "ProjectedYieldCalender.aspx/GetData" page returns an json data?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want all the events to be on a single event. Then this may help.

```
var string;
$.each(events, function() {
 string += "{title:" + this.title + "start:" + this.start + "}" ;
});
```